# How to disable clear button in ComboBox in vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I need a ComboBox without this clear button.  It confuses the users.
[image]

I believe in Vaadin 8 it could be removed with `setEmptySelectionAllowed(true);`. 
How can it be removed in vaadin 10? `setAllowCustomValue(false)` does not help. 
Java 8 
Vaadin 10.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to achieve that would be with CSS, at least that's how I would do it.

What you want to do is extend the default theme module for `VaadinComboBox` web component (see https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki/2.-Adding-Styles-to-Local-Scope), so you can use the following approach:

1. First, choose a CSS class name, like `my-combobox`
2. Next, create an HTML file that will contain the extension of the default theme module for VaadinComboBox web component. Give it a name like `my-combobox-theme.html` and put it into `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` (yes, it's `resources` twice)
3. Put the following into that HMTL file:

   ```
   <dom-module id="my-combobox-theme" theme-for="vaadin-combo-box">
       <template>
           <style>
               :host(.my-combobox) [part="clear-button"] {
                   display:none !important
               }
           </style>
       </template>
   </dom-module>
   ```

In the first line you declare that the following CSS is supposed to supplement whatever styles are defined for VaadinComboBox web component.

Then, the only CSS rule that is there defines that whenever there is a VaadinComboBox that has CSS class `my-combobox` the `clear-button` part of the web component should not be displayed.

4. Import the custom module to a view with `@HtmlImport("frontend://my-combobox-theme.html")`. NB: you need to add this annotation in all views that you want to use the modified ComboBox in. See point 6 for an alternative
5. Now you're pretty much all set. Whenever you want to have a `ComboBox` without delete button, just add a class name with `comboBox.addClassName("my-combobox")`
6. You probably want to use your ComboBox in more than one place, so a good idea is to create your own class. This gives you a reusable component and takes care of always having the right HTML import for custom style in place:

   ```
   @HtmlImport("frontend://my-combobox-theme.html")
   public class MyCombobox extends ComboBox {

       public MyCombobox() {
           addClassName("my-combobox");

           // Adding the following code registers a listener which
           // resets the old value in case the user clears the
           // combo box editor manually, e.g. by entering "".
           //
           // addValueChangeListener(listener -> {
           //     if(listener.getValue() == null) {
           //         setValue(listener.getOldValue());
           //     }
           // });
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Since **Vaadin 14** you can easily hide/show the clear button with

`comboBox.setClearButtonVisible(false);`
[API documentation](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0/com/vaadin/flow/component/combobox/ComboBox.html#setClearButtonVisible-boolean-)

I know you asked for Vaadin 10, but for completeness I wanted to add this here.

Comment: @BasilBourque hm I saw the method in the [V13 release presentation](https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-13), but I guess that must have been only for TextField at that point, hmm. Edited.

Comment: is there a way to attach a listener to the clear button ? In my case i am populating a grid based on combo box selection. If i am clearing combo selection i want to clear the grid too.

Comment: @ratish you can achieve that by using a ValueChangeListener on the comboBox itself, not the clearButton directly

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible at the moment but discussed as feature. See the Github issue [No way to disallow clearing selected value](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box-flow/issues/79). You can leave a thumbs up on that issue to emphasize its importance. IMO this is a must-have feature that should be implemented from the beginning.

The [roadmap](https://vaadin.com/roadmap) says something about a "Dropdown menu" upcoming in Vaadin 11 in Q3. This could be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I am using shadow-dom traversal of the clear button component inside the vaadin-combo-box (in this case, id:my-combo), and set the display property. (javascript)

```
var clear_button = this.$.my_combo.shadowRoot.querySelector("#clearButton");
clear_button.style.display = "none";
```